# Set a view's width to be relative to device screen programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have a horizontal `RecyclerView` with child elements which I want to change the width of to be a bit less than the current `match_parent` set via the layout. I want to do this so that the next element in list is a bit visible on screen.

In the adapter `onCreateViewHolder` I am doing this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
params.width = MainActivity.deviceWidth - (int) MainActivity.dpToPx(40.0f);
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

where `MainActivity.deviceWidth` is:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
deviceWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
screenDensity = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

and `dpToPx` is this function:

```
public static float dpToPx(float dp) {
    return (dp * screenDensity + 0.5f);
}
```

This works. however, I noticed that on different devices, the "margin" I am setting is not always the same. I.e. the next card in the RecyclerView is not always showing the same amount.

Is the `dpToPx` conversion correct? I might be missing something else in my calculation but I am not sure what.

## Update

Changing:

```
params.width = MainActivity.deviceWidth - (int) MainActivity.dpToPx(40.0f);
```

To:

```
params.width = (int) (MainActivity.deviceWidth *0.9);
```

works!. I am fine with this solution. I just want to know why the previous one does not work...

Comment: I do not know if this helps you but have you tried considering using `ViewPager` instead. It has a method to clip of next element. In that case you would not have to worry about devices